# robots.txt for website hosted in a subdirectory

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, robots.txt

I have 2 website which is hosted in a shared hosting.
1st website
*example.com* hosted in a root directory as `/public_html/`

2nd website
*example2.com* hosted in a sub-directory directory as `/public_html/example_2/`

I have this in `example.com/robots.txt`

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /example_2/
sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

I have this in `example2.com/robots.txt`

```
User-agent: *
sitemap: https://www.example2.com/sitemap.xml
```

I want google to index both the website separately but do not mixed each another, what I know is if a website is submitted then google scrap whole directory, except the `Disallow` one; So if I `Disallow: /example_2/` will it effect `example2.com`. If so then what is the best way to write `robots.txt` for 2 website.

I'll be very great-full if some one can show me the right path.

Comment: You are seriously over-thinking this. ;-) The directory for example2.com is /public_html/example_2/. This is where you put your robots.txt for this site. ***Nothing more needs to be done.*** Why? because /public_html/example_2/ and by extension example_2/ is a local directory and not a directory on your site. It is not seen by the web. Cheers!!

Comment: ok @closetnoc, so my both `robots.txt` are good and I dont have to do any thing at this point of time right? and yes as it is not my cup of coffee so I thik 5 times before adding a single drop of sugar.

Comment: I like how you put it better! When it is not ***my*** cup of coffee, I put salt in it... but that is not what you meant is it? [humor] You should be fine. Cheers!!

Comment: he he, thanks. So you can put this as an answer then I can accept it, and let other developer like me to know how much salt not to add ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that for cPanel, and perhaps others, certainly to be expected with web hosts these days, while creating a second or third web site or even a sub-domain, cPanel in order to save on setting file permissions, creates any additional site within the web space of the first site created. This may be a result of the old Apache schema using httpd.conf and compatibility. Who knows? The result is that there is confusion and potential problems that can arise.

/public_html/ is the original sites web space for example.com

/public_html/example_2/ is the second site for example2.com

For example.com, the `directory` directive within the configuration file points to /public_html/ and for example2.com, the `directory` directive within the configuration file points to /public_html/example_2/.

These are local directories on your file system and not how things are seen from the web.

What is put into /public_html/ such as index.html will be seen as example.com/index.html and what is put into /public_html/example_2/ such as index.html will be seen as example2.com/index.html.

The same will be true for robots.txt and any .htaccess file you choose to create. Example.com robots.txt would go into /public_html/ and example2.com robots.txt would go into /public_html/example_2/.

The drawback to this configuration is that example.com/example_2/index.html will show the sites home page for example2.com/index.html. This is generally not a problem. Just something to remember.